# Log out users when shutting down computer via Applescript

Tags: applescript

I am using the following Applescript to run a Time Machine backup, and then shut down OS X on the computer at our store.

```
do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/backupd-helper"

repeat
    delay 10
    if not IsProcRunning("backupd-helper") then
        ignoring application responses
            tell application "loginwindow" to «event aevtshut»
        end ignoring
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat

on IsProcRunning(theProc)
    try
        do shell script "ps auxc | grep \"" & theProc & "\""
        return true
    on error
        return false
    end try
end IsProcRunning
```

It works fine and shuts down the computer unless  another user is logged in, then the `Security Agent` window pops up asking for an administrator username and password.

I'm curious if someone can help me add to this script the ability to check if the `Security Agent` window is open, and if it is, to enter the username and password in their relative fields?

Answer (score 2):

If you can go to sleep instead of shutting down, it wouldn't require administrator privileges or confirmation from other logged in users:

```
do shell script "tmutil startbackup -b"
tell application "System Events" to sleep
```

You could also use `shutdown` (it ejects disks properly and so on, but you could lose some unsaved changes):

```
do shell script "tmutil startbackup -b && shutdown -h now" with administrator privileges
```

A shell function that could be added to `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`:

```
tmshut() { sudo -s -- 'tmutil startbackup -b && shutdown -h now'; }
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I'm a little confused on how to implement it. First off, are you suggesting that I just put the computer to sleep instead of shutting it down? If I use your second idea, of using `shutdown`, how would I work that into my existing code? Or would I just replace my code with yours?

Comment: I edited the answer. `tmutil -b` basically replaces the code posted in the question. (`tmutil` = Time Machine utility, added in 10.7; `-b` = block, or wait until the backup has finished.)